# Find the points on the curve $y=x+e^x$ at which the tangent line is horizontal.

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

> Find the points on the curve $y=x+e^x$ at which the tangent line is horizontal.

The answer was $(0,1)$, but I don't get it. I tried to take the derivative of the function and equal it to $0$ but the final result was $\ln(-1)=x$, which is not defined. Can someone please clarify ??

Comment: The answer would make sense if the problem read $y = x - e^x$.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is correct?

Comment: Your work is correct. There is no point for which the tangent line is horizontal. One way to see this is that the function in question is monotone increasing (meaning its derivative is always positive). Are you sure it isn't $x - e^x$?

Comment: I think the question is wrong. Thanks anyway